# Why is dragged item hidden when lockToContainerEdges is true?

Tags: react-sortable-hoc

I have applied lockToContainerEdges={true} and lockOffset="0%" to my SortableList from react-sortable-hoc. There is a weird interaction, the dragged element stays in position and the one in the position you drag it disappears. if I unset those values and lock the y axis it works fine, it's just when I lock the elements to containers. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: @Delorean I haven't back then.